# PcakgeInstallationCommand is failed with "No TOKEN named force:base.cardSpacingMargin found"

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx-cli, package, package-install, cli

PackageinstallCommand is failed with below issue,

CLI Version: SFDX-CLI 7.96.1

```
ERROR:  Encountered errors installing the package!,Installation errors: 

1) (intelligentDiscoveryStatus) No TOKEN named force:base.cardSpacingMargin found, Details: intelligentDiscoveryStatus: No TOKEN named force:base.cardSpacingMargin found

{

  "status": 1,

  "name": "Error",

  "message": "Installation errors: \n1) (intelligentDiscoveryStatus) No TOKEN named force:base.cardSpacingMargin found, Details: intelligentDiscoveryStatus: No TOKEN named force:base.cardSpacingMargin found",

  "exitCode": 1,

  "commandName": "PackageInstallCommand",

  "stack": "Error: Installation errors: \n1) (intelligentDiscoveryStatus) No TOKEN named force:base.cardSpacingMargin found, Details: intelligentDiscoveryStatus: No TOKEN named force:base.cardSpacingMargin found\n    at force.toolingRetrieve.then.request (/usr/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/lib/package/packageInstallCommand.js:94:27)\n    at tryCatcher (/usr/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)\n    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)\n    at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)\n    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)\n    at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18)\n    at _drainQueueStep (/usr/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)\n    at _drainQueue (/usr/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)\n    at Async._drainQueues (/usr/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)\n    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/usr/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)\n    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)\n    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)\n    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)\nOuter stack:\n    at Function.wrap (/usr/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/@salesforce/core/lib/sfdxError.js:171:27)\n    at PackageInstallCommand.catch (/usr/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/ToolbeltCommand.js:248:46)",

  "warnings": []

}
```

Can you help me understanding this issue?

Comment: Is this _your_ managed package? If not, you need to talk to the vendor about this issue.

Comment: yes this is a managed package.

Comment: I understand that it is a managed package. Are you developing this managed package, or are you attempting to install a third-party managed package?

Comment: We developed this managed package and it was installing well since many months on fresh scratchOrg, but observing this issue intermittently since a week.